# How to return std::iter::Map from trait method?

Tags: rust

I have a vector of tuples:

```rust
let l = vec![(0, 1), (2, 3)];
```

And I'd like to get `std::iter::Map` which extracts the first element for each tuple. Naively, this works:

```rust
let m: std::iter::Map<_, _> = l.iter().map(|e| e.0);
```

Now I'd like instead to extend `Iterator` to make this pseudo code work:

```rust
let m: std::iter::Map<_, _> = l.iter().tuple_first();
```

### Attempt 1

I tried to return `impl Iterator`:

```rust
trait TupleExtractor<'a, T1: 'a, T2: 'a>: Iterator<Item = &'a (T1, T2)> {
    fn tuple_first(self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a T1>;
}

impl<'a, T1: 'a + Copy, T2: 'a, I> TupleExtractor<'a, T1, T2> for I
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a (T1, T2)>,
{
    fn tuple_first(self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a T1> {
        self.map(|e| e.0)
    }
}
```

This code doesn't compile because

```
`impl Trait` only allowed in function and inherent method return types, not in trait method return types
```

### Attempt 2

I tried to explicitly return `std::iter::Map` instead of `impl Iterator`. However, this code doesn't compile either for the same reason.

```rust
trait TupleExtractor<'a, T1: 'a, T2: 'a>: Iterator<Item = &'a (T1, T2)> {
    fn tuple_first(
        self,
    ) -> std::iter::Map<impl Iterator<Item = &'a (T1, T2)>, impl FnMut(&'a (T1, T2)) -> T1>;
}

impl<'a, T1: 'a + Copy, T2: 'a, I> TupleExtractor<'a, T1, T2> for I
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a (T1, T2)>,
{
    fn tuple_first(self) -> std::iter::Map<I, impl FnMut(&'a (T1, T2)) -> T1> {
        self.map(|e| e.0)
    }
}
```

### Attempt 3

As the reason why the attempt 2 doesn't work is I cannot specify the type arguments of `std::iter::Map`, I tried to make them type parameters:

```rust
trait TupleExtractor<'a, T1: 'a, T2: 'a, A, B>: Iterator<Item = &'a (T1, T2)> {
    fn tuple_first(self) -> std::iter::Map<A, B>;
}

impl<'a, T1: 'a + Copy, T2: 'a, I, F> TupleExtractor<'a, T1, T2, I, F> for I
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a (T1, T2)>,
    F: FnMut(&'a (T1, T2)) -> T1,
{
    fn tuple_first(self) -> std::iter::Map<I, F> {
        self.map(|e: &'a (T1, T2)| e.0)
    }
}
```

This code doesn't compile because the closure `|e: &'a (T1, T2)| e.0` is not of the type `F`:

```
= note: expected type parameter `F`
        found closure `[closure@src/main.rs:38:18: 38:35]`
= help: every closure has a distinct type and so could not always match the caller-chosen type of parameter `F`
```

---

How to return `std::iter::Map` from trait method? I don't want to use `Box`.

Comment: Your first attempt will work in future rust versions. Until then I believe there is no way other than dynamic dispatch. Unless existential types get stabilized *before* allowing returning `impl Trait` in traits, in which case you'd use those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Rust version 1.75](https://releases.rs/docs/1.75.0/), you will be able to write `impl Trait` as a return type. This makes your Attempt 1 (when fixed for correctness) work unchanged. The only other effect is that you'll need to remove the type from `m` since it is now opaque.

I've simplified your trait to make things a little easier to read, but this technique also works for your original trait with all the generics. In particular, you may want to retain the `T1` generic in the trait.

```rust
trait TupleExtractor {
    type TupleItem;
    fn tuple_first(self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Self::TupleItem>;
}

impl<'a, T1, T2, I> TupleExtractor for I
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a (T1, T2)>,
    T1: Copy + 'a,
    T2: 'a,
{
    type TupleItem = T1;
    fn tuple_first(self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Self::TupleItem> {
        self.map(|e| e.0)
    }
}
```

1.75 comes out at the end of 2023. The general concept, called ["return position impl trait in trait" (RPITIT)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/91611), was added specifically for desugaring [async traits](https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2023/05/03/stabilizing-async-fn-in-trait.html) into `impl Future`. You can try this today by using the beta or nightly versions of Rust.

Comment: Thank you. Marked as accepted because Rust 1.75 will be released in a few weeks. Also, I could confirm the statement *"This makes your Attempt 1 (when fixed for correctness) work unchanged"* was correct: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3f6fe0d3a164e57de40d1c11aa47328b)

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of to work around this is to disallow using capturing closures (because their types cannot be named in traits (yet)) in favor of function pointers. Then you can define your trait with an associated type instead of the return position impl trait. This obviously does restrict the possible implementations but it still allows the use case you've shown:

```
trait TupleExtractor<'a, T1: 'a, T2: 'a>: Iterator<Item = &'a (T1, T2)> {
    type Mapper: Iterator<Item = T1>;
    fn tuple_first(
        self,
    ) -> Self::Mapper;
    //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ replace return position impl trait with associated type
}

impl<'a, T1: 'a + Copy, T2: 'a, I> TupleExtractor<'a, T1, T2> for I
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a (T1, T2)>,
{
    type Mapper = std::iter::Map<I, fn(&'a (T1, T2)) -> T1>;
    //                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ we can actually name this type
    fn tuple_first(self) -> Self::Mapper {
        // implementation stays the same because this is just an anonymous function
        // not a closure
        self.map(|e| e.0)
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_tuple_first() {
    let v = vec![(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b')];
    assert!(v.iter().tuple_first().eq([1, 2, 3].into_iter()))
}
```

If the `Mapper` type needs to be more extensible for other potential trait methods, you can make it generic over the type of item it yields:

```
trait TupleExtractor<'a, T1: 'a, T2: 'a>: Iterator<Item = &'a (T1, T2)> {
    type Mapper<T>: Iterator<Item = T>
    where
        T: 'a;
    
    fn tuple_first(
        self,
    ) -> Self::Mapper<T1>;
    
    fn tuple_second(
        self,
    ) -> Self::Mapper<T2>;
}

impl<'a, T1: 'a + Copy, T2: 'a + Copy, I> TupleExtractor<'a, T1, T2> for I
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a (T1, T2)>,
{
    type Mapper<T> = std::iter::Map<I, fn(&'a (T1, T2)) -> T> where T: 'a;
    
    fn tuple_first(self) -> Self::Mapper<T1> {
        self.map(|e| e.0)
    }
    
    fn tuple_second(self) -> Self::Mapper<T2> {
        self.map(|e| e.1)
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_tuple_first() {
    let v = vec![(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b')];
    assert!(v.iter().tuple_first().eq([1, 2, 3].into_iter()))
}

#[test]
fn test_tuple_second() {
    let v = vec![(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b')];
    assert!(v.iter().tuple_second().eq(['a', 'b', 'b'].into_iter()))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Using your answer as a hint, I just come up with a different (but very similar) implementation. How about this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a21af95b9eac863af8c8d29eb9b289e7))? No associated type is required.

Comment: You need to generate a permalink to share a playground (try the `share` button in the top right).

Comment: Ah, sorry. Updated the original comment.

Comment: That can't happen with associated types.

Comment: Currently I just understand your comment partially. In the playground you gave, I think the second trait implementation itself isn't valid (even if the first one is commented out). Could you give me a complete example? By the way, one advantage of my implementation is it is easy to extend the trait to define `tuple_second()`, `tuple_third()`, etc. without adding associated types `Mapper2`, `Mapper3`, etc.

Comment: Thank you. In this case, two trait implementations conflict with each other. So is it possible to happen that all of these conditions are satisfied: (1) two trait implementations are defined without conflict, and (2) the use of trait method gives ambiguity? As the purpose of this discussion (for me) is to understand Rust itself, it is ok to stray off the`std::iter::Map` example.

Comment: Actually, since GATs are stabilized (Rust 1.65), you can use that to make the trait easy to extend while avoiding conflicts: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d70ebcbda9aec1a4a11ad4c754ed3c18).

Comment: I get more confused now... According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76495790/how-to-return-stditermap-from-trait-method/76495867?noredirect=1#comment134877875_76495867), *it allows you to implement the trait for the same type multiple times*, but [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76495790/how-to-return-stditermap-from-trait-method/76495867?noredirect=1#comment134878053_76495867) says *You can't implement a trait twice for the same type without conflict*. Is this a contradiction or am I missing something?

Comment: Replying to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11423104/isaactfa), your GATs solution is very beautiful, and more beautiful than my impl. I'll use it. Thank you.

Comment: Great, I'll put it in the answer as well then.

Comment: Replying to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76495790/how-to-return-stditermap-from-trait-method/76495867?noredirect=1#comment134878140_76495867), the code doesn't compile even if I make `main()` empty ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=37bfb18f05fb673bdde81365a5bf2319)). So is this sentence correct?: *conflicting trait implementations (snip) 're fine. But when you call a trait method, the compiler might not be able to figure out which implementation to choose without type annotations, leading to a compile error.*

Comment: What I'd like to say in the previous comment is this: The code doesn't compile even if I don't call the trait method at all (i.e. after making `main()` empty). So isn't the conflict itself a problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254118/discussion-between-isaactfa-and-ynn).

Comment: Thank you for opening a chat room. Just joined.