# How can I represent Map, Filter etc Outputs?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a couple of traits for `&[u8]` and `Vec<u8>` to make my code more readable, but I cannot find out how to define Map/Filter/Split Outputs.

E.g

```rust
trait IoAsciiExt<'a, Item, F> 
    where F: FnMut(&Item) -> bool
{
    fn splitlines(self) -> Split<'a, Item, F>;
}


impl<'a, F> IoAsciiExt<'a, u8, F> for &[u8]
    where F: FnMut(&u8) -> bool
{
    fn splitlines(self) -> Split<'a u8, F> {
         self.split(|&char| char == 10u8)
    }
}
```

While there is a simple workaround for this particular example with `split(u8)` and `io::Split<Self>`, I still cannot find out how to represent closures properly for outputs like:

- Map<I, F>
- FilterMap<Self, F>

Can you give me an example of how to return mappers without collecting first?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76495790/how-to-return-stditermap-from-trait-method/76495867#76495867 (possibly dupe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all comes down to not being able to name the closure types in traits ([yet](https://rust-lang.github.io/impl-trait-initiative/RFCs/rpit-in-traits.html)). The easiest -- and hopefully sufficient in your case -- way to deal with this, is to not use closures but function pointers:

```
use std::slice::Split;

trait IoAsciiExt<'a, Item> {
    fn splitlines(self) -> Split<'a, Item, fn(&Item) -> bool>;
    //                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

impl<'a> IoAsciiExt<'a, u8> for &'a [u8] {
//                              ^^^^ need to actually use the lifetime here
    fn splitlines(self) -> Split<'a, u8, fn(&u8) -> bool> {
         self.split(|&char| char == 10u8)
         //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         // closures that don't borrow anything coerce to `fn(...) -> ...`
    }
}
```

See also ["How to return std::iter::Map from trait method?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76495790/11423104)

By the way, you can get rid of the lifetime in the trait by receiving `self` by reference in the method:

```
trait IoAsciiExt<Item> {
    fn splitlines(&self) -> Split<'_, Item, fn(&Item) -> bool>;
}

impl IoAsciiExt<u8> for [u8] {
//                      ^^^^
//                      impl'ing on the bare slice now
    fn splitlines(&self) -> Split<'_, u8, fn(&u8) -> bool> {
        self.split(|&char| char == 10u8)
    }
}
```